# How to check if there is an object in a 2D list

Tags: python, list

How do I check if there is an object located in a specific index of a 2D list?

I would like to access the object and send it off as a parameter for another object.

This object is not in the same class as the 2D list, but it is in a class that is imported.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Do you mean you want to check the type of an object? Or simply access it in a 2D list? Or you just want to know if the index is valid?

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'm still quite new to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is

```
try :
    if my_array[i][j] : #Checks if the array contains something not empty
        if isinstance(my_array[i][j], YourObjectType) :
            print "We have a type YourObjectType at position %d, %d" % (i, j)
except : 
    print "Ouch, nothing in the position %d,%d" % (i, j)
```

Comment: @RobertHarvey : What do you mean?

Comment: He is saying that no one really knows what the OP is asking, so you did a best guess answer.

Comment: I see, quite frankly i though i understand the question, maybe my English?

Comment: Well you can see that the other answer goes a completely different direction. So obviously there is some ambiguity. Hence why the OP is being downvoted.

Comment: Very ambiguous question. +1 to Juan though, for inspiring the second half of my post

Comment: You may be right guys, and again, maybe it is my English but i really though that I understood the question, in the past, I have found other people that did not now about the "isinstance()" function in python :)

Comment: No no, don't misunderstand. You are just as right as anyone here. Its the OPs fault for making people guess. This is probably what he wants. You might want to make sure the indexing doesn't raise an exception though.

Comment: Yes, this is kind of what I was looking for. :)  +1 for you!  @jdi - "may the force be with you to understand StackOverflow questions in the future"

Comment: @RahulSharma: And may the force be with you to take more time to write out a question that people don't have to guess at answering :-)

Comment: @jdi : You are totally right, i just added the exception :) Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `__eq__` is properly defined for this object, then you could do this:

```
myObjInstance in itertools.chain.from_iterable(my2dList)
```

Or, if this is more along the lines of what you want:

Assuming that you want to check the outer index `x` and the inner index `y`:

```
try:
    if isinstance(my2dList[x][y], MyObjectClass):
        print "Yay! there's a MyObjectClass object there. Sending it off as a param to the other function now…"
        myOtherFunction(my2dList[x][y])
    else:
        print "Yay! there's an object there"
except IndexError:
    print "Boo! no object there"
```

Comment: Maybe catch an `IndexError` specifically?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the second part is the thing the OP is asking. Thats my best guess.

Comment: @jdi: there! I made it even closer to what I think OP wants

Comment: BTW, I really like that `itertools` approach.